# Interface not reloaded after returning to app from BACK press

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-actionbar

I currently have a set of tabs, each tied to a fragment, and I've finally gotten the UI on one of the tabs to look how it should. Here's a screenshot of how the app looks when it has properly loaded (after initial launch and scrolling to a tab): [image] Now, after I hit the back button (I haven't and won't be bothering with a backStack for each tab - I don't like that UI paradigm) and then use app switcher or relaunch from the launcher, my questionRows are gone (they don't reload). Do I need to implement something in onPause to save my display? Why doesn't onResume take care of it this?

```
package com.davekelley.polling;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class EconFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewGroup container;
    private TableLayout questionContainer;
    private ScrollView scrollView;
    private ViewGroup econFragment;
    static int pos = 0;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Econ", "onCreateView");
        this.container = container;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.econfragment, container, false);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        questionContainer = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.questionContainer);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //these lines are my first attempt to try and get the questions to repopulate after returning
        //from pressing back - as of yet, they don't repopulate the screen:
        //View econFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.econfragment, null);
        //container.addView(econFragment);

        int leftMargin=5;
        int topMargin=5;
        int rightMargin=5;
        int bottomMargin=5;
        while (pos < 10) {
        View question = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, null);
        question.setId(pos);
        pos++;
        TableRow tr = (TableRow) question;
        TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        trParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
        tr.setLayoutParams(trParams);
        questionContainer.addView(tr);
        }
        Log.d("Econ", "onResume");
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Log.d("Econ", "onAttach");
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Econ", "onCreate");

    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Econ", "onActivityCreated");
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("Econ", "OnStart");
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();    
        Log.d("Econ", "onpause");
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("Econ", "onstop");
    }

    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.d("Econ", "ondestroyview");
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("Econ", "ondestroy");

    }

    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        Log.d("Econ", "ondetach");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question kinda got put on the backburner as I worked on other areas of my app. It turns out the solution was a simple one: the pos variable as listed in the code was static, so the while loop could not reclimb from 0-10. Here's the answer: [Even though onCreateView runs again, View does not properly reassemble after BACK press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960035/even-though-oncreateview-runs-again-view-does-not-properly-reassemble-after-bac/9960160#9960160)

Answer (score 1):

Each Activity has own lifetime cycle from *onCreate* to *onDestroy*. Take a look at picture and very detailed article here: [Activities Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle)

Your activity go though cycles and die automatically when user pressed *PowerButton* or *BackButton*. When you turn power or relaunch then activity starts from begin (*onCreate*).

You should implement *save* and *load* functions and save state on *onPaused* callback and load state *onResume* callback. It will prevent from loosing state of your activity between restarts.

Comment: Thank you, I will read the link you provided with a bit more depth tomorrow morning. I had already started trying to save my state a little bit in onPause, because, as you can see, I have Log entries for each method, so I could see that I was losing my stuff after onPause, but I am confused as to why the UI is not simply recreated when I come back to it, as my UI is built in onResume, which I can see via log, reruns when I return.

I will look into more around the methods putInt, putString, etc, but I think it will be a bit of a stretch for me to grasp how to save UI via these type methods.

Comment: So after running through the article, and I have more to absorb, I think I know the problem here. In a fragment, onCreateView runs after onCreate (my main activity builds from this method). So I can't add elements to my layout (which is inflated in onCreateView) in a method that runs earlier. Any ideas?