# My Activity state is lost upon device sleep (lock/unlock)

Tags: android

I have an issue that when I leave the android device idle for a bit (it sleeps and locks, then I have to unlock it), it seems that my OnCreat method is called again because my variables are resetted and the layout is redrawn again!
Is there a way I can preserve the state and continues from where it was after its being unlocked (or awaken again)?
Thank you very much

Comment: Read doc... About Activity life cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go out of your activity (pressing back, a call is received, pressing home, locking, etc) the acitivity calls the `onPause()` method and then loses all saved information (unless you use only the provided widgets in the Android framework).

Therefore you need to save that information overriding the `onPause()` method. Then you need to load that information in the `onResume()` method.

For more information check: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the life cycle of Activity. I wrote about this problem here:
 [Interface not reloaded after returning to app from BACK press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830123/interface-not-reloaded-after-returning-to-app-from-back-press/9834887#9834887)